# Rails 4- Associations -Tutorial Movielist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Hi I am trying to use Rails on Rest 2 - movielist tutorial with rails 4 and making adjustments as I go for new rails. I  am stuck on associations of Movies Roles. I have added to Movie.rb

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :people, :through => :roles
validates_presence_of :title
  def new_role=(values)
    values.each do |i, hash|
      unless hash[:name].blank?
        roles.create(:person_id => hash[:person_id], :name => hash[:name])
        roles.save
      end
    end
  end

 def deleted_roles=(values)
   values.each do |role_id|
      roles.find(role_id).destroy
    end
  end

end
```

and also to show _Form.html.rb that I render (excert below)

```
 <b>Add New People</b><br />
    <% (1..3).each do |i| %>
      <%= select_tag 'movie_new_role_person_id', options_for_select(@people), {
        :name => "movie[new_role][#{i}][person_id]"
      } %>
      <%= text_field_tag 'movie_new_role_name', '', {
        :name => "movie[new_role][#{i}][name]"
      } %><br />
    <% end %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </p>
```

It renders the list to choose from but when i submit - nothing is written to database table.
If I manually enter data in database then it displays on movielist page ie: "Stephen Spielberg - Director" etc...
Any help appreciated- Driving me nuts at this stage

I thought it might be params driven restriction but I do not have a good example of associations style params filter

Thanks

Alan

Comment: Try changing "create" to "create!" in order to throw an error.

Comment: Thanks Chicagogrrl . I added that and did what I should have done from the start and debugged the console output more closely. Issue was related to the params as expeted and once I figured out teh syntax for adding methods to params.permits it worked fine. Won;t be making that mistake again so maybe was worth the two days hair pulling. thanks again . I have added teh syntax i used to the answer section in case it is of interest

Answer (score 0):

After debugging including Chicagogrrl's !flag I investigated the params.permits in the movies_Controller again and figured I would have to add  the method types to the list of excepted. I could not find detailed info on syntax for this but trial and error paid off.

```
  app/controllers/movies_controllers.rb (excerpt)
 ......
     # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
      def movie_params
       params.require(:movie).permit(:title,:description, :rating, :role, :deleted_roles=>[], 
        :new_role=> ['person_id', 'name'])
     end
```

......

The delete_roles=>[] takes the array params and process to delete_roles method in movies.rb
the new_role=>['person_id', 'name'] takes the new_role individual params.

I Hope this saves somebody else some time andIf anybody needs anymore info just ask thanks again Alan